# How to use log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, buildpath

I am trying to use Log4j. I have added both the Log4j.jars (log4j-api-2.5.jar) and (log4j-core-2.5.jar) to my classpath and am still getting this error when I build:

**error: package.org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
public class LoggingTabController extends BaseController
{
    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingTabController.class.getName());

@FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        logger.trace("Entering Log4j Example.");

  }
}
```

Any idea why I still can't use it?

Comment: What does your classpath look like?

Comment: Why would you *implement* Log4j. Wouldn't it be much easier *using* the already existing Log4j implementation?

Comment: Please show us how you specify the classpath and invoke the program.

Comment: as @Andreas mentioned, the more common approach is to use Log4j's Logger class as is instead of implementing your own class.  Could you show us how you're configuring log4j?  You'll usually do that in a log4j.xml or log4j.properties file.  Posting that would be helpful.